# Why would the "civicrm_queue.runner" property be missing?

Tags: import, data-import

I am trying to import contacts and getting the following errors:

Cannot execute queue "user_job_6". The "civicrm_queue.runner" property is missing.

[image]

Any idea why?

5.61.4 wordpress

Edit: this issue fixed itself after 24 hours - using same dataset.

Comment: if you haven't already, would it be worth retrying the import with just one row of data to check it is nothing to do with any of the data in the csv?

Comment: I assume you are using the core importer? Also replicated the error with the API CSV Importer.

Comment: I think the answer is below - it’s a roll of the device which task in the civicrm_queue table gets executed - I suspect the queue table is supposed to be empty eventually. Mine has 55 records in it - are these vestiges of aborted earlier tasks?

Answer (score 3):

I've come across a similar issue. Looking in the database I could see a row in the `civicrm_queue` table with the same name but `NULL` for `runner`.

I fixed the issue by deleting that row in the table and performing the import again. The import then worked as normal.

I have a suspicion that there may be a bug with CiviCRM core and I've created an issue for this:

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4554

The reason that it may work sometimes and not others is that CiviCRM will choose a different job number for each import. It depends whether that particular job number has an entry in the `civicrm_queue` table as to whether the import works or not.

**Update**: this bug was fixed in CiviCRM 5.68 by https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/28051.

Comment: I believe you're absolutely correct. My table has mostly null values and if I start an import a dozen times, I eventually get past those and then it works. THANK YOU for creating an issue to get this fixed. In the meantime, can we just delete those user tasks that have Null in the runner field?

Answer (score 1):

I also replicated the "civicrm_queue.runner property be missing" issue using external ID's using the API CSV Importer. On another [post Laryn points out external ID's failed](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9857/how-do-you-import-custom-relationship-fields), so simply do a CID to external ID mapping pre-processing first.

Sample data format

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update - got it to run, as alluded to above - to get this import to run, I repeatedly started it, noting the user_task_xx was different each time, and I was getting these task numbers in roughly increasing numerical order - I continued until the job number was one of those that did NOT have Null in the runner name column. So now I feel sure that those records are the issue. Does anyone know whether the records for user job can be deleted for those where the Runner Column has "null" instead of "task"? (and no, I don't know why this is bolded!)

========================

I am having this same problem with trying to import "do not email" flag for a batch of contacts. This worked fine a few days ago, but failed multiple times today. I have cut down the file to small batches and finally to one record and then eventually to just two columns ("contact ID" and "Do Not Email") and keep getting the same error. Looking at the civicrm_queue table, I see 54 records in the civicrm_queue table, with each row having a Name of "user_job_xx" where xx is a number from 1 to 59. The jobs names are in ascending order with a few numbers skipped, up to 48, which is then followed by one of the skipped numbers. So all the sequential queues have a value of "null" for the column "Name - name of the task runner". After the break in the increasing numbers, the job 7 has a runner name of "task" and all the rest also have that name. Is it possible this table is corrupted, and could some records be deleted? The post above indicates that a task number is chosen at random, so this might work next time I try it?

[image: civicrm_queue table contents showing the transition from null to task for name of task runner]